# Cucumber options annotation

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

The cucumber-jvm [javadocs](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.Options.html#glue%28%29) states that purpose of the glue element is to specify the location of the stepdefinitions and hooks. However, this doesn't seem to work for me. Lets say I have my features in directory a, and my step definitions in directory b. Then,

```java
@Cucumber.Options(
        features= "directory_a", 
            glue="directory_b"
)
```

will load my feature files from directory_a, but, it doesn't load my step definitions from directly_b. However, if I use

```java
@Cucumber.Options(
        features= {"directory_a", "directory_b"}
)
```

then my features from directory_a is loaded, and my step definitions from directory_b are also picked up. Which is exactly what I want, however, I don't understand why the former isn't working? I'm guessing it has something to do with it expecting the URI to be formatted differently (maybe i need to prepend a classpath:// or something like that), but I can't find any information on this in the documentation.

Comment: @Cucumber.Options is deprecated now, use [CucumberOptions](http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/CucumberOptions.html)

Comment: I'd mark this question as outdated.

Answer (score 20):

I have successfully used something like:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
    //this code will only look into "features/" folder for features
    features={"classpath:features/"},
    glue = { "com.mycompany.cucumber.stepdefinitions", "com.mycompany.cucumber.hooks" },
    format = { "com.mycompany.cucumber.formatter.RuntimeInfoCatcher", "json:target/cucumber.json" },
    tags = { "@working" }
    )
public class CucumberStarterIT {
}
```

Looking at the doc at http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/junit/Cucumber.Options.html it specifies the options to be of type `String[]` so perhaps it's not expected to work "well" if you don't give it a single-value list. Try `glue={"directory_b"}` and see what happens for you.

Comment: It's not clear from the example above or the documentation, but glue only takes package names.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem too... and so far it *seems* to be that:

"features" is looking for a **filesystem path**:

```
features = "src/foo/bar"
```

whereas "glue" is looking for a **package name**:

```
glue = "foo.bar"
```

Not sure why they are different, but this seems to be working for me.

Comment: The answer to why they are different is that features are loaded from a directory, for example a resources directory. Glue loads actual compiled classes from the mentioned package *AND* all sub-packages recursively, regardless of where they are on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per my knowledge it all depends on the structure of you project. For example if you add the "Directory_a" ( directory which contains feature files) in the root level and StepDefinition, Hooks at src > test > java "Directory_b" And the TestRunner class at the same level ( src > test > java ) in "Directory_c"

```
Dir_a
|
src
   |---main
   |---test
          |------java
                     |------Dir_b
                     |------Dir_c
```

You saying "Dir_b" while you are in the "Dir_c" It will identify "Dir_b" or any directory in same level with out any additional paths so,
It will be 
glue = {"Dir_b"},
But when you look at the directory that includes feature file you have to give the path from the root level
In this case it's
features = {"Dir_a"}
or Giving the actual path eg :- "E://Project_Name//Dir_a" should work too

If your feature directory is NOT in root level make sure you give the path like "src/path to feature directory"

It will work fine :)