# Unable to find the features file?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am running `Cucumber JVM` for a POC with `Selenium 2.37`.

The folder structure of my project as follows

```
 src
     >> main   
      > test
            >java
                 >package
                         >TestRunner.java
                         >StepfDef.java
            >resource
                 >package
                         >bdddemo.features
```

When i run the test runner via Junit, i am getting the following error message.

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:
No features found at [classpath:test/java/com/package]
```

I believe the folder structure has some issue.

Can anybody post me where the `Cucumber-JVM` is actually looking for story files by default ?

Comment: You can override the location with the Options tag, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491989/cucumber-options-annotation

Answer (score 1):

By default, when using classpath:, Cucumber starts looking in the root of you classpath.

If you configure Cucumber to search in "classpath:features", you can put your features in src/test/resources/features.