# Cucumber: Unable to see methods of a module included in the World?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm working with cucumber/ruby and I wanted to create a new module with some methods to use them in my step definitions.

I was reading how to do this here, https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World. But when I've tried the following I get an error:

- create the new module under /root_location/lib/new_module.rb
- create the module as:

.

```
module Newmodule
  def here
    puts "here"
  end
end
World(Newmodule)
```

However, when I then try to use the 'here' method from my steps definition, I just get:

> undefined local variable or method `here' for # (NameError)

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why the cucumber-jvm tag?  Your question is ruby focused not Java.

Comment: Because as you can see from the answer below, it is NOT a ruby question, it has to do with the cucumber framework... so I guess that's always the case regarding of the language.

Comment: That answer wouldn't work for cucumber-jvm.  You need to define glue directories.  See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491989/cucumber-options-annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module needs to be located in `features`, otherwise it won't be added into World. Cucumber does not look outside of features for anything unless you specifically tell it to.

Put this code either in `features/support` or `features/step_definitions`

Comment: Thank you diabolist, I didn't know that. 

Knowing that, I created a file.rb under support, where I required the ruby file that I've got in my library and exported to the World from here. 

Many thanks!