# Cucumber with Spring Config doesnt work, can't run tests: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, spring-boot-test, cucumber-junit

im trying to setup a cucumber with spring project to use autowiring and spring config options (application.yml). Now that i created a runner class to pass parameters from outside executing runs on following exception:

[image: Error Message]

Weird is, i have a class exactly with the proposed annotations, so i guess it's not found and something on the project structure is off, but i don't get what exactly.
Here is my project structure:

```
 src.main.java.package.config.SpringConfig.java
 src.main.java.package.steps.StepsSpringConfig.java
 src.test.java.package.runner.CucumberRunner.java
```

**SpringConfig.java**

```
@ComponentScan("package")
@EnableConfigurationProperties{PropertyClasses}
```

**StepsSpringConfig.java**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringConfig.class)
@CucumberContextConfiguration
```

All Step classes extend from this class

**CucumberRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(steps = path/to/features, glue = {src.package.steps, src.package.config})
```

In my JUnit RunConfig I use this runner class

When i run i get the error on the screenshot above. What am i missing?
Im using the latest version of IntelliJ (2021.2.2)
Im using Spring 2.3.12 and cucumber-junit 6.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok im dumb, the solution is found here: [Cucumber options annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491989/cucumber-options-annotation)

i specified the glue path like "src.main.java.package.steps" but it needs to be just "package.steps" and it works fine