# Error: io.cucumber.core.backend.CucumberBackendException: Please annotate a glue class with some context configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-spring

I have integrated Cucumber with Spring Boot.
When I run the **CucumberTestRunner** from the IntelliJ it is giving the following error.

[image: Error Screenshot for reference]

Below is the screenshot of the relevant code.

**SpringBootTest class:**

[image]

**CucumberTestRunner:**

[image: CucumberTestRunner Class]

**POM.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.alok</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SampleProject</name>
    <description>Sample Project for Selenium</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber Dependencies - START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
            <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Cucumber Dependencies - END -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have already tried the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461291/cucumber-with-spring-config-doesnt-work-cant-run-tests-io-cucumber-core-backe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491989/cucumber-options-annotation) but it is not working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: The error mentions a `@CucumberContextConfiguration` annotation that I don't see in your code.